# подсчет количества товара

Tags: jquery

> На форме выбирается количество ящиков и автоматически меняется сумма у Ящиков и итоговая сумма. Считается отдельно количество товара и меняется итоговая сумма.
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<label for="jashiki">Ящики</label>
<input type="number" id="count_jashiki" name="Количество ящиков" value="1" />
<span id="price6"> 1700</span> руб <br>
<br>
<input type="number" id="count" name="Количество товара" value="1" /><br>
<label for="count"> Итого:</label>
<span id="final_price">7500</span> руб
```

> jQuery

```
$('#count').keyup(calculate);

 function calculate() {
   var sum = 0;

   //количество товара: 
   var count = $("#count").val();
   sum = count * sum; //сумму умножаем на количество

  //количество ящиков: 
  var count2 = $("#count_jashiki").val(); 
  sum3 = count2 * 1700; //кол ящиков * цену ящика
  sum += sum3; //суммируем получившуюся сумму ящков с общей суммой 
    //сумма ящиков вывод на страницу
    $('#price6').html(sum3);

   //итоговая цена:
   $('#final_price').html(sum);
 }

 $('select,input').change(function() {
   calculate();
 });
```

Comment: А в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: не правильный  подсчет итоговой суммы

Comment: @Лиана А как должно быть?

Comment: Зачем вы "количество товара" (`count`) умножаете на ноль? Может, сначала нужно посчитать сумму (`sum`), а потом уже умножать на `count`?